# Strategy to delete 500k rows of data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently there is a table in my android sqlite database that contains around 500k of records. It takes around 11 seconds to delete on my laptop but it takes forever to delete on my smartphone.

I tried to drop the table but it just hang there. Is there any strategy to solve this? I've stuck at this problem for few hours! :(

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {                
            StockDocRepo repo = new StockDocRepo(this);
            repo.deleteInactiveRecords();                                
        }
    }).start();
```

The `deleteInactiveRecords()` method is just  pure SQL raw query:

```
DELETE FROM stockloc WHERE active = "0"
```

**EDIT : After hours of finding i found that the database in my android smartphone failed to pass PRAGMA INTEGRITY_CHECK which caused system to throw "Database disk image is malformed" exception which I've failed to catch when trying to drop the table.**

**Final solution i've taken is to rename the original table to "stockloc_temp" and then recreate "stockloc" table and insert all the records i intended to keep into the new table. Old table is then drop. Voila its done!**

Comment: post the code so far!

Comment: I tried to run delete command in a background thread. It is just few lines of code. I will edit my post together with code. A sec please.

Comment: Just a random idea: can you store the entire data set that must be dropped in a single database file, and simply delete the file?

Comment: looking at your code will help understand the problem better. Share.

Comment: copy remaining data to other table and drop this table

Comment: @Mike good idea. I will try out and test the performance. Thanks!

Comment: @Kilanny i tried to drop the whole table and it takes forever :( Not sure why tho

Comment: @raj will try! Thanks man!

Comment: you can also use hadoop with sqlite which is used for big data

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Thanks alot! Will look into it and post my solution later on :)

Comment: Android SQLite isn't intended for storing large set of data. Those probably need to be stored at server side.

Comment: @Styx Try to `dbFile.delete()` and re-create your entire database

Comment: @raj It is a bug in our web service that returns irrelevant data to webservice consumer (aka my android apps). This bug is discovered today when user feel that the app is getting real slow when querying the table. So we are not intended to use other technologies to solve this matter because it can be achieve by fixing the webservice and cleanup the table.

Comment: @Hi I'm Frogatto It is a bug in our web service that returns irrelevant data to webservice consumer (aka my android apps). This bug is discovered today when user feel that the app is getting real slow when querying the table. So my idea is to do a cleanup the table but i am bother with the delete performance that's why i am posting on here to look for a viable strategy.

Comment: @Kilanny there are other tables in the database where user-input data is stored and there is no way to rebuilt if the whole db file is deleted. :(

Comment: @Mike I applied your solution but I stored data I intended to keep in a new table and dump the old table. Thanks.